# Android - ORM based database library to create tables dynamically at run time

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, dbflow

I am developing a chat application in Android using ORM library `DBFlow`. Currently, I need to create table for each conversation with a person, dynamically for a new/existing conversation. I can do this using default SQLite implementation, but not with the `DBFlow` library as `we need to create class for each table before-hand`.

Is there any other ORM based library available for Android with which I can create tables dynamically at run-time.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of table definitions are you considering for your app? One table that has every conversation with a single person (this may not be an optimal design as you might end up creating a huge number of similar tables - one for each person)?  Or one table that has all the conversations with every person (perhaps identified with a person id and conversation id)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure. You can use [ORMLite](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android). [Here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html) example of the dynamic creation of the table.
Also you can see for the [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html), which create table for a new entity automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.